# Why is my mergesort slower than my quicksort?

Tags: java, sorting, time-complexity, quicksort, mergesort

They're both the same time complexity but when I run my merge sort on a randomly generated linked list with 100,000 entries:

```
public LinkedList<Integer> linkedListSort(LinkedList<Integer> list) {
    if (list.size() <= 1) return list;
    LinkedList<Integer> left = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    LinkedList<Integer> right = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    int middle = list.size()/2;
    for (int i = 0; i < middle; i++) {
        left.add((int)list.get(i)); steps++;
    }
    for (int i = middle; i < list.size(); i++) {
        right.add((int)list.get(i)); steps++;
    }
    left = linkedListSort(left);
    right = linkedListSort(right);
    return merge(left, right);
}

public LinkedList<Integer> merge(LinkedList<Integer> left, LinkedList<Integer> right) {
    LinkedList<Integer> result = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    while (!(left.isEmpty()) && !(right.isEmpty())) {
        steps++;
        if ((int)left.peekFirst() <= (int)right.peekFirst()) {
            result.add(left.poll());
        } else {
            result.add(right.poll());
        }
    }
    while (!(left.isEmpty())) {result.add(left.poll()); steps++;}
    while (!(right.isEmpty())) {result.add(right.poll()); steps++;}
    return result;
}
```

It's a lot slower than my quick sort which is:

```
public String arraySort(int[] array, int startIndex, int endIndex, int steps) {
    int leftIndex = startIndex;
    int rightIndex = endIndex;
    int pivot = array[(leftIndex + rightIndex) / 2];
    while (leftIndex <= rightIndex) {
        steps++;
        //search for an element with a higher value than the pivot, lower than it
        while (array[leftIndex] < pivot) {steps++; leftIndex++;}
        //search for an element with a lower value than the pivot, higher than it
        while (array[rightIndex] > pivot) {steps++; rightIndex--;}
        //check the left index hasn't overtaken the right index
        if (leftIndex <= rightIndex) {
            //swap the elements
            int holder = array[leftIndex];
            array[leftIndex] = array[rightIndex]; 
            array[rightIndex] = holder;
            leftIndex++; rightIndex--;
        }
    }
    if (leftIndex < endIndex) arraySort(array, leftIndex, endIndex, steps); 
    if (rightIndex > startIndex) arraySort(array, startIndex, rightIndex, steps);
    return "Quicksort on an unsorted array took " + steps + " steps.";
}
```

What's the reason for this? Is my quicksort/mergesort not what it should be or is it that mergesort performs badly on a linked list with a large amount of random numbers? Or something else?

Thanks!

Comment: How are you measuring the speed of each? Are you using a micro benchmark framework or just executing one after the other naively?

Comment: Why did you expect mergesort to be faster than quicksort?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I haven't been measuring it properly, but i have to wait at least 10 seconds for my mergesort to finish but my quicksort doesn't take a noticeable amount of time. Also I have been measuring the amount of comparisons made by each on and  quick sort will take about 75000 and mergesort will take 3337856.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I just expected them to be about the same time since they're the same time complexity

Comment: @ErlangBestLanguage That is not what the time complexity tells you, not exactly. There are many other factors, including hidden constants in the time complexities themselves. You're right to expect comparable performance in this case though.

Comment: Are you sure you are not passing the array that was already sorted by the merge sort to the quicksort?

Comment: @RealSkeptic very sure, what makes you think that?

Comment: Because if the input is sorted, this quick sort will do only comparisons, no swaps. Very quick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've implemented a version of quicksort that's doing everything "in-place" while your mergesort copies the content of left/right upon every recursive call (and same thing with `merge()`). That's probably the major reason for the differences.

Second, like Luiggi mentioned in the comments above - how do you do your benchmarking ? do you get a proper JVM warmup? do you run enough cycles and take average ?  proper benchmarking with the JVM can be tricky: if you don't have experience with it, better look for a [micro-benchmarking framework](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) and use it!

Comment: That's a good point actually, I'll reconsider how I'm doing my mergesort then! Thanks! Also I haven't dabbled in any proper benchmarking it was mainly because it took noticeably longer to execute, but I'll look into that thanks!